# C++ Map exc_bad_access (Apple only)

Tags: c++, macos, dictionary, exc-bad-access

[Code](https://github.com/TheEmpty/Just-Another-2D-Game-Engine--for-lack-of-a-better-name-/blob/5b31742a6fb5ff23049e5109382d2bc13bc06a5a/Platformer/Map.cpp#L80-87)

[Reads from](https://github.com/TheEmpty/Just-Another-2D-Game-Engine--for-lack-of-a-better-name-/blob/master/Release/maps/revisited.txt)

On Windows 7 and 8 it runs fine. However, when running in XCode 4 I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the second iteration when someone loads a map (select "Load Map" from title).

You can download the source with the [XCode project](https://github.com/TheEmpty/Just-Another-2D-Game-Engine--for-lack-of-a-better-name-/downloads)

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

std::map <std::string, std::string> info;    

std::string* get_key_val( std::string* line )
{
    std::string key_val[2];
    int start, end;

    start = line->find_first_not_of( " " );
    end = line->find_last_of( ":" );
    if( start == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if( end == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        key_val[0] = line->substr( start, end - start );
    }

    start = line->find_first_not_of(" ", end + 1);
    end = line->find_last_of( " \n\r" );
    if( start == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if( end == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        key_val[1] = line->substr( start, end - start );
    }

    return key_val;
}


void parse_from_line( std::string* line )
{
    std::string* keyv = get_key_val( line );
    if( keyv[0].empty() == false && keyv[1].empty() == false ) info[ keyv[0] ] = keyv[1];
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    std::string line = "name: Foo";
    parse_from_line( &line );
    std::cout << "Hello " << info["name"].c_str();
}
```

Comment: Is there a simpler example of this problem?  You're asking people to do a lot of reading and research.  (You might also solve the problem in the process)

Comment: Mat: Yes, I linked to it with the lines, should have copied the code, sorry.

DrewDormann and Sam Miller: I had been trying, but was unable to reproduce it. Though I think it's because I was doing everything in main versus adding another function, would have been easy to recreate now that I know the problem, I'll go ahead and add an edit above for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_key_val` function starts like this:

```
std::string* Map::get_key_val( std::string* line )
{
  std::string key_val[2];
```

It ends like this:

```
  return key_val;
}
```

You're returning a pointer to a stack variable. The `key_val` variable ceases to exist upon return from the function, so you have an invalid pointer, and the two string values in the array get destroyed. Subsequent behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I remember considering this but think I got too frustrated and forgot. Now what I'm doing is `void Map::get_key_val( std::string* line, std::string* key, std::string* value );` is that the "proper" way to go about it?

Comment: That could work. I'd pass those parameters by reference instead of by pointer, though: `void Map::get_key_val(std::string const& line, std::string& key, std::string& value)`.

Answer (score 0):

With move semantics in C++11 onwards, its less necessary to do this. You can just return std::string and the move operator should avoid any wasteful copies.